# Moderators cannot edit profiles of users who are active on Channels

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, moderator-tools

Stack Overflow ♦ moderators cannot edit the *public* Stack Overflow profile of a user that's currently active in a channel.

We can however still edit the profiles of other users and we can edit the public profile of a user once they have left a channel though.

Comment: I immediately see two ways that this could be abused to do Bad Things™ so this is not a trivial bug.

Comment: I wonder if that's an explicit enforcement or the result of some horrible dependency à la [xkcd 1700](https://xkcd.com/1700/)...

Answer (score 5):

For now, just use the "Contact CM team" functionality and indicate what needs to be taken out. We'll get something better in place after we see what (and even how) we might be able to "split" profiles for users attached to one or even multiple teams. Consultants come to mind as a strange use case there.

Kind of related, I'm in the middle of re-writing our guidance for what to do in cases of user emergencies (e.g. when mods notice that a user made a threat to harm others or themselves) which is *also* going to include a way for mods to page a CM on 'beeper duty' during off hours if there's a super-high sense of urgency. While I really doubt that mods would need to use this for an offensive avatar that couldn't keep to the next day, the functionality to get it done very quickly will soon be in the system. You'll be able to flag a "Contact CM about user" message as critical, and it will be beamed to someone's phone.

Anyway, there will be a separate announcement about that sent to mods (well, made public on MSE with a ping in the mod inbox to let folks know it's there).

Sorry about the confusion, I'm still not 100% sure how a `MultipleProfilePersonalitySuperProfileSuperCollider` is going to eventually work in this context, but we'll do our best to keep the workflow sane and a bit more obvious in the tooling as that works out.